# How do I transfer the SOL on my token account?

Tags: spl-token, send-transaction, spl, spl-associated-token-account, sol

I have a token account (example: https://solscan.io/account/3HJdseEK7G8cDEcDQPNmt5z1TuVb5AjCPxvqJCpkskbQ?cluster=devnet) and accidentally sent some SOL to it. I want to transfer this out to my SOL wallet. How do I do this? All the wallets will only let me send USDC from this token account

Answer (score 2):

The process is clunky, but to get the additional SOL out of a token account, you need to move the USDC to another account, close the account to retrieve everything, recreate the account, then move the USDC back.